Reference Request: A general approach to forcing, and some clarification
I've wanted to understand forcing for quite some time now, but I wish to understand it in the general sense of formal logic, rather than just the specific case of set theory, which I find quite confusing anyways. However, I'm struggling to find sources which take this approach, making me doubt it exists. I recall reading somewhere that Cohen forcing had been generalized into a proof-method in logic outside of just set theory, or even mathematical logic. Am I misremembering this, or perhaps have a misconception? If not, what sources could I look at to see an explanation of forcing which takes this approach? Every source I see explains forcing in the context of set theory, and then maybe hand-waves what it would look like in a more general sense. I'd prefer if this was flipped.
Any help is greatly appreciated! If you'd like to provide a full answer/explanation of your own, then I'd greatly appreciate it, but I wouldn't expect something so detailed and so this is largely just a reference request.

The nLab page on forcing provides some general references. Forcing is nowadays understood as working in some (pre)sheaf topos, which is applicable outside of set theory; see e.g. The independence of Markov's principle in type theory.

Maybe this is what you have heard of: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3185188

Nik Weaver's Forcing for Mathematicians is a marvelous book. It demands "no background in logic is assumed, beyond the facility with formal syntax which should be second nature to any well-trained mathematician" (in the author's words), and similarly, in set theory (in my words).
The path leading to the demonstration of the independence of the Continuum Hypothesis is worked out step by step in a most lucid manner. Then, "applications outside of set theory which were previously only available in the primary literature" are examined (I insert the contents of the book below).

For logic-related matters, a tidy source is Melvin Fitting's Intuitionistic Logic, Model Theory and Forcing (freely available to read). This book might need to be supplemented with some papers, by Andrej Grzegorczyk and Saul Kripke, in particular. Jeremy Avigad's "Forcing in Proof Theory" (mentioned in the comments) would definitely help a better grasp of the general view.
